# OpenVZ - Failed to get ploop stats: No such process

Tags: vps, openvz, ploop

Can anyone assist? I can't even create template cache or anything. All fails with "ploop" errors. Ploop is installed and can be ran directly.

This is OpenVZ 7.

```
[root@virt1 ~]# vzpkg create cache ubuntu-22.04-x86_64
Creating OS template cache for ubuntu-22.04-x86_64 template
The operation has completed successfully.
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=128 blocks, Stripe width=256 blocks
655360 inodes, 2620928 blocks
131046 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=2151677952
80 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done 

tune2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Setting maximal mount count to -1
Setting error behavior to 2
Setting interval between checks to 0 seconds
mv: cannot stat ‘bin/*’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘lib/*’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘libx32/*’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘lib32/*’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘lib64/*’: No such file or directory
Error: Failed to get ploop stats: No such process
E: Unable to determine a suitable packaging system type
Error: /usr/bin/apt-get failed, exitcode=100
Error: Failed to get ploop stats: No such process
Error: Failed to umount ploop image /vz/tmp//vzpkg.hkYSkv/cache-private/root.hdd: Error in ploop_umount_image (ploop.c:2817): Image /vz/tmp/vzpkg.hkYSkv/cache-private/root.hdd/root.hds is not mounted 40
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar issue today when installing a new openVz bare-metal server with a debian-12 container. In my case I had to downgrade from OpenVZ release 7.0.**21**  to OpenVZ release 7.0.**20** , after that no problem at all.

You can also check those things :

1. You got the template on your system (should be there /vz/template/ubuntu/22 and appear in the list given by `vzpkg list -O`), if not try to add it via `vzpkg install template ubuntu-22.04-x86_64` (in my case it was quite impossible to make it work and I have surrended here and downgrade )
   here doc source for this part : https://docs.openvz.org/openvz_users_guide.webhelp/_updating_ez_templates.html
2. If you cannot update it and are more efficient than me you can found the ubuntu-22 template here : https://download.openvz.org/virtuozzo/releases/7.0/x86_64/os/Packages/u/

You can maybe got a hint by looking :

1. /var/log/ploop.log since the error is mentioning it.

Good luck to you